# Лишние пробелы в консоли Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, консоль

```
public void checkForCommand(DatagramPacket packet) {
    String message = new String(packet.getData());
    if (message.startsWith(connectionPacket)) {
        extractingUserData(packet);
        return;
    } else
        System.out.println(clientName + ": " + message);
}

private void extractingUserData(DatagramPacket packet) {
    clientAdress = new String(packet.getAddress().toString());
    clientPort = new Integer(packet.getPort());
    String message = new String(packet.getData());
    parts = message.split(" ");
    clientName = parts[1];
    System.out.println("User: " + clientName + clientAdress + " " + clientPort + " "
            + "successfully connected to the server!");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не ясно откуда появляется такое количество пробелов в консоли. Причем если разбить строку на две примерно так:

```
System.out.println("User: " + clientName);
    System.out.println(clientAdress + " " + clientPort + " "
            + "successfully connected to the server!");
```

Проблем с пробелами не возникает. Логично предположить что пробелы приходят вместе с переменной clientName. Вопрос как это исправить, ведь очевидно что имя задается без пробелов вовсе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что переменная clietName шла в конце пакета из 1024 байтов. Соответственно все "пустые" байты после тоже печатались в консоль. Решением было применить метод trim(); во время извлечения имени из пакета данных.